# jquery ajax simple array as parameter is converted to associated array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to post a complex json object to an ajax jquery, but it seems impossible to keep a simple array without having it transformed to an associated array with "0", "1"... as keys.

request:

```
var dimension_set = [{ 'x': 1, 'z': 2, 'y': 3 }, { 'x': 4, 'z': 5, 'y': 6 }];
var parameters = { "dimension_set": dimension_set };
jQuery.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: WEBSERVICE_URL, data: parameters });
```

Parameters:

```
dimension_set[0][x]:1
dimension_set[0][z]:2
dimension_set[0][y]:3
dimension_set[1][x]:4
dimension_set[1][z]:5
dimension_set[1][y]:6
```

---

while i would like this:

Parameters:

```
dimension_set[][x]:1
dimension_set[][z]:2
dimension_set[][y]:3
dimension_set[][x]:4
dimension_set[][z]:5
dimension_set[][y]:6
```

Is there any way to get this ?

---

Note: it's feasible via curl, or an http form.
Request:

```
curl -X POST WEBSERVICE_URL -F "dimension_set[][x]=1" -F "dimension_set[][y]=2" -F "dimension_set[][z]=3" -F "dimension_set[][x]=4" -F "dimension_set[][y]=5" -F "dimension_set[][z]=6"
```

Server side print:

```
  Parameters: {"dimension_set"=>[{"x"=>"1", "y"=>"2", "z"=>"3"}, {"x"=>"4", "y"=>"5", "z"=>"6"}]}
```

Comment: Those aren't keys. Those are indexes.

Comment: How would you discern between the parameters passed to the server?

Comment: How can you make the difference between this:  
dimension_set[][x]:1  
dimension_set[][z]:2  
dimension_set[][y]:3  
And this:  
dimension_set[][x]:4  
dimension_set[][z]:5  
dimension_set[][y]:6  
.  
The same array element have different values? That's not possible, so you have to get an index.

Comment: see my edit, I guess the parameters are ordered, but it works for html forms and curl parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a jquery "feature".
In this documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/
see the last line:

```
$.param({ a: { b:1,c:2 }, d: [3,4,{ e:5 }] }) // "a[b]=1&a[c]=2&d[]=3&d[]=4&d[2][e]=5"
```

Apparently, what I want (no index in the parameter array 'd') is not possible for complex objects, only for integers !